Slope stability in the algebraic and analytic case
I'm trying to get an understanding on two different definitions for stability. The first one comes from Friedman's book on algebraic surfaces and holomorphic vector bundles.

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety of dimension $d$ and let $H$ be an ample line bundle on $X$. Then for a torsion free coherent sheaf $E$ on $X$, the normalized degree $\mu_H(E)$ is given by $$\frac{c_1(E) \cdot H^{d-1}}{\operatorname{rank}(E)}.$$ Now $E$ is called $H$-(semi)stable if for all coherent subsheaves $F$ of $H$ we have $\mu_H(F) < \mu_H(E)$ (resp. $\mu_H(F) \le \mu_H(E))$.

So the given definition seems to depend on $H$ and I think that such a $H$ always exists due to $X$ being embedded in projective space.
The following is then the analytic analogue of this.

Define the degree of a holomorphic vector bundle $E\to (X,\omega)$ over a compact Kähler manifold to be the integer $$\mathrm{deg} (E) := (c_1(E) \cup [\omega]^{n-1})[X]$$ The slope of $E$ is the rational number $\mu(E)$ defined by $$\mu(E) := \frac{\mathrm{deg}(E)}{\mathrm{rank}(E)} = \frac{(c_1(E) \cup [\omega]^{n-1})[X]}{\mathrm{rank}(E)}.$$

I have a bit of difficulties understanding why does the first one seem to depend on an ample line bundle while the latter doesn't? Any smooth projective variety is a submanifold of the Kähler manifold $\Bbb P^n$ and hence itself Kähler so I don't see why the dependence on the ample line bundle is needed there? Any insights on this?

The Kähler class, i.e. $[\omega]$, is Poincaré dual to the hyperplane class $H$. In particular, choosing a projective embedding of $X$ determines the hyperplane class $H$ by intersection, or $[\omega]$ by pulling back.

Could you elaborate slightly on what do you mean that choosing the embedding determines the hyperplane class $H$ by intersection? If we have an ample line bundle $H$ on $X$, embedding $X$ into $\Bbb CP^N$ we can pullback the Fubini-Study metric to obtain a Kähler form $\omega$, but I'm not entirely sure what do you mean by intersection here. @AlekosRobotis
